# UICollectionView Header change height in IBAction

Tags: ios, objective-c

I would like to change the height of a header in `UICollectionView`. when i click on a `UIButton`.
What is the best way to do this ? 
After some research i could call `referenceSizeForHeaderInSection` but i don t know how to call this method in my `IBACtion`.
Any ideas ?
Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do is check if your button is clicked and based on that you can set your header size differently in your `referenceSizeForHeaderInSection` method. You can't explicitly call the `referenceSizeForHeaderInSection` method. Whenever the collection view is loaded or re-drawn, this protocol method gets called.

Let's say, whenever your button is clicked you set a flag in your IBAction method. Make sure you declare it within the class scope.

```
-(IBAction)buttonClicked{
    self.flag = YES;
    // do whatever you need to do here

    //reload your collection view here
    [self.myCollectionView reloadData];
}
```

In your delegate method, you set the header size based on the fact that if the button is clicked.

```
-(CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout referenceSizeForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
  {
  if (!self.flag) {
     return CGSizeMake(0, kHeaderHeight);
  }
  else{
    return CGSizeMake(0, kHeaderHeight + 50);
  } 
}
```

whenever you want to go back to your normal header size, just set the flag as NO and reload the collectionView again.

Comment: Thanks for your help, when i reloadData on collectionView, referenceSizeForHeaderInSection is called again. Do you think i can add an animation when the header scroll down ?

Comment: yes, you can. Research on UIView's animateWithDuration. However, to animate the header to expand, you probably need to work with the header's frame.

Comment: It's actually a waste to call reload data since the data is not changing in this case you should call `invalidateLayout` note my answer below with that it is also much easier to animate.

Comment: This is exactly what I did, but I like to have animation added as well. Did you manage to get it working?

Answer (score 5):

The way you want do it is make the delegate return a different height after you invalidate the layout.

```
-(IBAction) action {

 self.size = CGSizeMake(320,40);
 [self.collectionView.collectionlayout invalidateLayout];
}
```

in your delegate it should look something like that:

```
- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout referenceSizeForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    if (section == theSection)
        return self.size;

 return CGSizeZero;
}
```

Also make sure that the reusable view is in the right size.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this flow in your `IBAction`

```
    // Create a new UICollectionViewFlowLayout with new values

    let cFlowTest = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    cFlowTest.itemSize = CGSizeMake(40, 40) // your default collection cell size
    cFlowTest.minimumInteritemSpacing = 44 // spacing
    cFlowTest.minimumLineSpacing = 44 // spacing
    cFlowTest.estimatedItemSize = CGSizeMake(40, 40) // if you'll use auto - sizing set this property and don't set 'itemSize' and make sure your constraint supported this
    cFlowTest.scrollDirection = .Vertical // or .Horizontal
    cFlowTest.headerReferenceSize = CGSizeMake(300, 40) // set your new header size
    // cFlowTest.footerReferenceSize = CGSizeMake(300, 40) // set your new footer size if you have

    // Then update your collectionView's flowlayout using this two methods
    // 1.
    collectionView.setCollectionViewLayout(cFlowTest, animated: true)

    // or
    // 2.
    collectionView.setCollectionViewLayout(cFlowTest, animated: true) { (isFinished) -> Void in
        // your additional code here
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Swift 5:

```
self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout()
```